# CAS overlay redirect logout to another URL

Tags: spring, overlay, cas

Using CAS Overlay 5.1 Spring Boot CAS Authentication Server. 
I want to redirect the logout from `https://ip:8443/cas/logout` to `http://ip:8080/app/page.html`
In my cas file I have activated:

```
cas.logout.followServiceRedirects=true
cas.logout.redirectUrl=http\://ip\:8080/app/page.html
```

also for my session I use LDAP and my service registry I have:

```
{

  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "^http://ip:8080/app/.*",
  "name" : "CAS Spring Secured App",
  "description": "Cas",
  "logoutUrl" : "http://ip:8080/app/page.html",
  "logoutType" : "BACK_CHANNEL",
  "id" : 1001,
  "evaluationOrder" : 0,
  "attributeReleasePolicy" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllowedAttributeReleasePolicy",
    "principalAttributesRepository" : {
      "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.DefaultPrincipalAttributesRepository"
    },
    "authorizedToReleaseCredentialPassword" : false,
    "authorizedToReleaseProxyGrantingTicket" : true
  } ,
  "publicKey" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegisteredServicePublicKeyImpl",
    "location" : "classpath:RSA1024Public.key",
    "algorithm" : "RSA"
  }
}
```

The problem is that it always takes me to the page (image), what am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> cas.logout.followServiceRedirects=true

This only works when you submit requests as `/cas/logout?service=http://ip:8080/app/page.html`

> cas.logout.redirectUrl=http://ip:8080/app/page.html

- This should be `http://ip:8080/app/page.html`
- An open-redirect to an HTTP URL is suspicious practice.
- This property [does not exist](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#logout) for CAS 5.1.x.

Comment: Perfect!! Solution